# How to prevent blank page at the end with jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report containing a table with dynamic content on the left side and a frame containing static fixed size text on the right side:

[image]

Below you find the jrxml source (I removed the title and three columns of the table to reduce the size):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-08-10T11:19:14 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="WaterlevelForecastReport" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" resourceBundle="messages" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="3cf70749-5058-4a53-ad3e-091553a6ed3e">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
<style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" isBlankWhenNull="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="8" isBold="false">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="DataStyle" hTextAlign="Center" isBlankWhenNull="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="8" isBold="false"/>
<subDataset name="WaterLevelForecastDataSet" uuid="01de13e9-d88f-4fef-b1bf-4de28bf02e6a">
    <parameter name="waterlevelForecastData" class="com.example.reporting.WaterlevelForecastReportService.WaterlevelForecastData">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <field name="waterLevel" class="com.example.WaterLevelForecast">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="logo" class="Object" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="waterlevelForecastData" class="com.example.reporting.WaterlevelForecastReportService.WaterlevelForecastData">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="200">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="42" uuid="a532b32e-a9e0-427b-84c4-d60fe9589d84">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="42" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f4166ea1-a21d-4ed8-8f16-02ae243c81f1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="WaterLevelForecastDataSet" uuid="15b7c136-4802-4b6b-bd8c-cbde01ec9bed">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{waterlevelForecastData}.getWaterlevelForecastList())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="d70db54d-dd19-40c3-a36c-1d9592008fcc">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement style="Table_CH" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7fa06c16-b4cc-450e-a204-6fe97e18c1a4">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Datum]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="12">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="75c92bc7-279f-4ea5-95dd-2005b43669f2">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($F{waterLevel}.getTime())]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="570" y="0" width="230" height="200" uuid="386949ed-e289-4e9d-82af-54f7a1afbb6e"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="11" width="59" height="12" uuid="a63c6262-34f9-4731-9ad4-22bf6a2a54d2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Pegelort:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="31" width="59" height="12" uuid="d56daa72-b14f-442b-8868-4bba5601f47f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Position:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="51" width="58" height="12" uuid="056f6c4b-375e-4d88-8aa4-900da296b655"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MHW (mPN):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="71" width="57" height="12" uuid="30d9f8de-2612-4c2a-b319-39b01f6d2809"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MNW (mPN):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="91" width="57" height="12" uuid="51b3bc61-c9f3-4b48-9f72-df980ea80c2e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[PN (mNN):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="111" width="218" height="12" uuid="ddaea131-e7f8-4215-bada-f489b37896a9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Der Wasserstand bezieht sich auf Pegelnull.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="123" width="29" height="12" uuid="54323c5e-1213-441f-9bda-41b6415d9158"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[HW]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="135" width="29" height="12" uuid="9974d608-8a33-4f35-ae72-07388f9ae138"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[NW]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="147" width="29" height="12" uuid="428c7ee2-46c1-4008-b355-8ac357c51057"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MHW]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="159" width="29" height="12" uuid="81b95147-96f0-4227-b9a9-cf51c5db0c8c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MNW]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="183" width="29" height="12" uuid="38ef4fc2-05dd-4aae-8510-c50002d2492e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[NN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="11" y="171" width="29" height="12" uuid="8c9e77a4-65ea-4ef4-b8e4-b4b3620c3f0e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[PN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="123" width="160" height="12" uuid="66fd279e-95db-4970-b70f-aaa298929472"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Hochwasser]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="135" width="160" height="12" uuid="03b13ac8-169c-419c-a407-749b41c55f4a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Niedrigwasser]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="147" width="160" height="12" uuid="f5bc3c27-f772-44d7-8679-f69a52d0f3e8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Mittleres Hochwasser]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="159" width="160" height="12" uuid="8124681f-f321-4cde-986b-458318ef925f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Mittleres Niedrigwasser]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="171" width="160" height="12" uuid="8bd1a23e-b9a6-48c9-afc3-8d01a901327a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Pegelnull]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="DataStyle" x="40" y="183" width="160" height="12" uuid="96bb6dce-c1cd-490b-93f5-5aca18234fe2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <text><![CDATA[= Normalnull]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="30">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="10" width="800" height="20" uuid="0d80af3a-fdab-42df-a876-9debf03164e8">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{label.hvcc.disclaimer}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

If I generate a PDF file from this report template, I'm always getting a blank page at the end, containing only the page footer and no content.

For my understanding this is because of the space between the table on the left side and the bottom of detail band 1, that will be added to the end of the table when the report is generated. So if the table and the space below is to large for one page, an additional page is added to the PDF containing only the space and footer.

If I remove the frame on the right side and reduce the height of detail band 1 to the end of the table, everything is fine and no extra page will be added. But I need this space in the report template because of the frame on the right side containing the static text.

How can I change the report template to reduce the height of detail band 1, so that no space below the table will be added to the PDF but with no effect to the definition of the frame on the right side?

I tried it many times by changing the stretch and overflow options but I'm always getting a blank page at the end.

**Workaround**

If I use a subreport for the frame on the right side and setting the height of the subreport element to the same height of the table on the left side, the height of detail band 1 can be reduced to the end of table and in the generated report no space will be added after the table and no extra page will be rendered.
But I thought there is a possibility to achieve this without using subreports.

Comment: Post a minimal working example JRXML code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is it one left table per row? Does left table contains many rows?

Comment: There is one table on the left side, that contains many rows.

Comment: Use frame in detail band and put your table and static field inside that frame. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it but the result is still the same. If I have around 25 entries in the table, the space from template between the table and the footer is still added after the table in the generated document.